# jQuery selectors - traverse dom in more robust way?

Tags: jquery

When you click the trigger, the code below will turn the 2nd div.four red and not the first one.

I understand why this is happening but can I solve it without something like .nextAll('.parent').child() ? My html may change eg the first div.four might end up in 2 div.parents, so id like a solution that would still work.

Is there a more robust way of traversing the dom eg finding the next div with a certain class regardless of how many levels down it is?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.trigger').click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('.four').css('background-color','red');         
     });
 });​

<div class="trigger">trigger</div>
<div class="one">one</div>
<div class="two">two</div>
<div class="three">three</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="four">four</div>    
</div>
<div class="four">four</div>    ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g9heg/1/

UPDATE

I should have specified but I need to have multiple triggers and targets in the same page. So for this fiddle, 'trigger 1' should target 'four' and 'trigger 2' should target 'Seven'. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/g9heg/5/